# Run script on every server request

Tags: bash, debian, networking, iptables, webserver

In Debian, is it possible to run a custom script on each server request? i.e. everytime someone tries to connect to the server, we run a quick script.

If I understand correctly, softwares like fail2ban monitor the logs and ban afterwards.

Ideally, I would like to do it before connection is granted, with the possibility to drop the connection on some condition.

Basically add an iptable rule on the fly as the request is made.

Is that possible?

Edit:

I guess it should be both UDP/TCP protocols?
It's run with systemd.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it a UDP service?  Or a TCP service?  Is it run from `xinetd`?  From `tcpserver`? From `systemd`?  Please [edit] the question to make it clear what server this is.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similiar to the concept of port knocking, which you can implement in iptables.  The concept is someone 'knocks' by connecting to a series of known ports, in order, and then are allowed to connect to a final port to complete a connection.